# Store Promise in Map to resolve/reject later

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, message-queue

I'm working on IPC in NodeJS and want to be able to send a message to the parent process from the child and "wait" for the result. My idea was to keep track of all the send messages in a map that maps the unique message ID to a promise. Once the `` process.on('message`) `` has been called I lookup the promise by the ID I got back from the parent and want to resolve or reject the promise.

I came up with this, but am stuck at the resolve/reject part:

```
'use strict'

import RequestMessage from "../messages/request/RequestMessage";
import ResponseMessage from "../messages/response/ResponseMessage";

const process = require('process');

export class CommunicationManager {
    private messageQueue: Map<string, Promise<any>>;

    constructor() {
        this.messageQueue = new Map();

        process.on('message', (payload: any) => {
            if (payload.hasOwnProperty("_id")
                && this.messageQueue.has(payload.get("_id"))) {

                let promise = this.messageQueue.get(payload);
                // Resolve or reject the promise..

                this.messageQueue.delete(payload.get("_id"));
            } else {
                console.error(`Got unknown message from parent: ${payload}`);
            }
        });
    }

    public execute(message: RequestMessage): Promise<ResponseMessage> {
        process.send(message);
        this.messageQueue.set(message.id(), // a promise here);
    }
}
```

Can someone push me in the right direction on how to solve this? Is this even possible and best-practice?

Thanks!

Comment: what about putting the `this.messageQueue.set(message.id(), // a promise here);` on the 'message' listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not store the promise in the map. You would store only the resolver function to call later - the promise is created and returned immediately.

```
init() {
    process.on('message', (payload: any) => {
        if ("_id" in payload && this.messageQueue.has(payload._id)) {
            const resolve = this.messageQueue.get(payload._id);
            this.messageQueue.delete(payload._id);
            if (payload.isFulfilled) {
                resolve(payload.value);
            else {
                resolve(Promise.reject(payload.error));
            }
        } else {
            console.error(`Got unknown message from parent: ${payload}`);
        }
    });
}

public execute(message: RequestMessage): Promise<ResponseMessage> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.messageQueue.set(message.id(), resolve);
        process.send(message);
    });
}
```

It is rare to call `resolve` in some other scope than the promise executor's, but messaging is one of those cases where it is necessary and the standard practice. Btw, you might want to consider putting a timeout on the response receival.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi had a nice answer. I have a follow-up to anyone considering doing something like this: it's a concept called "Deferred/Deferable" that was hot for a while but fell out of favor over async/await - check this guide https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/javascript-resolve-promise-from-outside/ or even this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred

You would then store a *deferable* in your Map, return `deferred.promise` in your `execute()` and call `deffered.resolve()` whenever you want to actually resolve it.