# Get Promise resolve from separate callback

Tags: javascript, promise

I am sending data to a Bluetooth device, and the responses are handled by a listener that's set up during the connection process:

```js
device.connect().then(device => {
  device.registerResponseListener((data) => {
    // handle response
  }
}
```

I have a separate function that sends data to the device:

```js
const sendData = (device, data) => {
  device.write(data);
}
```

My question is, how can I Promisify this code? I'd like to be able to do

```js
const sendData = (device, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    device.write(data);
    // resolve...?
  });
}
```

But how do I get the `resolve` into the Bluetooth response listener?

Comment: You can probably use async/await

Comment: Why do you need to promisify this function? What problem are you solving?

Comment: Is there an opposite of `registerResponseListener` like `unregisterResponseListener`? Any documentation of this API?

Comment: You'll need [a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60517241/1048572) of `resolve` functions

Comment: @VLAZ Because I need to be able to chain a sequence of requests.

Comment: @trincot It's this https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ —but this question is not about the specific API, it's about how to handle the situation in general

Comment: In the situation in general you would read the documentation and see what it offers, so that you would not re-event the wheel and make use of the best services available. Can you point to the documentation of `registerResponseListener`? I don't find it there.

Comment: @T3db0t the solution to this in general is *not* to use a single listener (set up during connection) to handle all the responses. In the ideal case, the library you're using does natively support promises (and in fact the library you linked *does*!), if their API is suboptimal you have to work with what you got (and e.g. implement queuing or request/response-linking yourself, like in the answer I linked).

Comment: The API is promise-based but not in the way that I need for this. Responses to a write come ONLY from `monitorCharacteristicForService` (I used a simpler name in my example). I'll investigate the possibility of using the request queue—would it warrant a full answer here?

Comment: @T3db0t From a quick glance, there's [`writeCharacteristicWithResponseForDevice`](https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#blemanagerwritecharacteristicwithresponsefordevice) and also `readCharacteristicForService` which both return a promise for the response

Comment: @Bergi as I said, in this particular case, the ONLY way to receive the response is via the listener. All the promise does is return the Characteristic I was writing to.

Comment: @T3db0t What will happen if you call `write()` multiple times before the response is received? How can you match the response to the respective `sendData` call?

Comment: @Bergi Exactly what I’m concerned about

Comment: @T3db0t Is there a request id in the response? Are the responses just in the same order as the writes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238282/discussion-between-t3db0t-and-bergi).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/61937887/1048572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible solution in this case, while still not ideal, was to store the `resolve` function in variable at a higher scope:

```js
var sendDataResolve;

device.connect().then(device => {
  device.registerResponseListener((data) => {
    sendDataResolve(data);
  }
}

const sendData = (device, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sendDataResolve = resolve;
    device.write(data);
  });
}

...

sendData(device, "data")
.then(result => {
  console.log("Got result",result);
});
```

The caveat is that Promise resolutions are NOT guaranteed to be tied correctly to the original request. This ONLY works with one request at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what API you're using but you can try BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic API. It has writeValueWithResponse method which return Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic

Comment: This question is not about any API in particular, it's about what to do in this situation in general.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then you can do it like this

```
const sendData = async (device, data) => {
  const response = await device.write(data);
  await Promise.all(device.responseListeners.map(listener => listener(response)))
}
```